# PHP: Make Plugin apply on homepage in WordPress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the Smart Syntax plugin in my WP blog. It highlights syntax utilizing Google's prettify.

The syntax highlighting works perfectly with my custom CSS rules, but it seems like the Javascript applying the CSS to my posts isn't being applied when a post is viewed on the homepage.

Here's the plugin's `functions.php`:

```
<?php

function smart_syntax_prettyprint($content)
{
    global $post;
    global $comment;
    $seeker     = "/(<pre)(.+)(<code.+class.+[\'\"])([^\'\"]+)([\'\"]>)/i";
    $prettified = '$1 class="prettyprint lang-$4"$2$3$4$5';
    $content    = preg_replace($seeker, $prettified, $content);
    return $content;
}

function smart_syntax_prettify_script()
{
    global $post;
    global $comment;
    $content      = $post->post_content . $comment->comment_content;
    $smart_syntax = get_option('_smart_syntax_options');
    $output       = preg_match_all('/(<pre)(.+)(<code.+class.+[\'"])([^\'"]+)([\'"]>)/i', $content, $matches);
    // find language tags
    if (!empty($matches[0]) && isset($matches[0])) {
        $langs = smart_syntax_remove_dupe_langs($matches[4]);
        foreach ($langs as $lg) {
            if ($lg = 'css') {
                $lang = $lg;
            }
        }
    }
    if (is_singular() && !empty($matches[0]) && isset($matches[0])) {

        if (!empty($lang) && isset($lang)) {
            $suffix = '?lang=' . $lang;
        }

        if (isset($smart_syntax['cdn_prettify']) && $smart_syntax['cdn_prettify'] == true) {

            $source = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js' . $suffix;

        } else {

            $source = SMART_SYNTAX_URL . 'assets/js/src/run_prettify.js' . $suffix;

        }
        wp_enqueue_script('smart-syntax-prettify', $source, null, null, true);
?>
                <script>prettyPrint()</script>
            <?php

        if (isset($smart_syntax['custom_skin']) && $smart_syntax['custom_skin'] == true) {
            wp_enqueue_style('smart-syntax-skin', SMART_SYNTAX_URL . 'assets/css/smart_syntax.css', true, '1.0.0');
        } elseif ($smart_syntax['custom_skin'] != true && $smart_syntax['cdn_prettify'] != true) {
            wp_enqueue_style('smart-syntax-skin', SMART_SYNTAX_URL . 'assets/css/prettify.css', true, '1.0.0');
        }
    }
}

function smart_syntax_remove_dupe_langs($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $lang => $val)
        $sort[$lang] = serialize($val);
    $uni = array_unique($sort);
    foreach ($uni as $lang => $ser)
        $sorted[$lang] = unserialize($ser);
    return ($sorted);
}
```

And here's `smart_syntax.php`:

```
function smart_syntax_init() {
    $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', get_locale(), 'smart_syntax' );
    load_textdomain( 'smart_syntax', WP_LANG_DIR . '/smart_syntax/smart_syntax-' . $locale . '.mo' );
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'smart_syntax', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
    require_once SMART_SYNTAX_PATH . 'includes/functions.php';
    require_once SMART_SYNTAX_PATH . 'includes/admin-menu.php';
}

/**
 * Activate the plugin
 */
function smart_syntax_activate() {
    // First load the init scripts in case any rewrite functionality is being loaded
    smart_syntax_init();

}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'smart_syntax_activate' );

/**
 * Deactivate the plugin
 * Uninstall routines should be in uninstall.php
 */
function smart_syntax_deactivate() {

}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'smart_syntax_deactivate' );

// actions
    add_action( 'init', 'smart_syntax_init' );
    add_action('admin_menu','smart_syntax_menu' ); 
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','smart_syntax_prettify_script');

//filters

    add_filter('the_content', 'smart_syntax_prettyprint', 10);
    add_filter('comment_text', 'smart_syntax_prettyprint', 10);
```

I know very little PHP. Doing `add_filter('is_home','smart_syntax_prettyprint', 10);` didn't help.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the script isn't loading on the homepage is because the plugin is conditionally loading the script **only** on single posts and pages.

Inside `function smart_syntax_prettify_script()` you can remove `is_singular()` from this statement:

```
if (is_singular() && !empty($matches[0]) && isset($matches[0])) {
```

So that it reads:

```
if (!empty($matches[0]) && isset($matches[0])) {
```

**Important Note**

You will be editing the plugin itself, so it's recommended that you fork it in some way. Otherwise when the plugin author releases an update it'll override your change and revert it back.

You could also contact the plugin author and ask them to create an option to allow you to set on which page types the plugin should load.